# How to use threadfence / CUDA5.5

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cuda

So, I want to know how to use threadfence, and I want to read sample code about threadfence.

### please show me sample code about threadfence()

I believe when I want to access the memory is a kernel function of the device side in CUDA5.5, I want perform exclusive control.
I learned exclusive control is possible if I use what's called "() __threadfence" I do, I do not know what if I use how.

· What can I do include ?
    (now, the "__threadfence()" occur the error that wasn't defined identify )
· Where do I write the code on the source code.
  because I thought I would like to exclusively control the place you want to access the Log_d in the code below.

Other threads I want to prevent access with respect to memory of Log_d between "lock start" ~ "lock stop" the following code, for example.

I defined the blocks and threads at CPU side code.
blocks : 1,1,1   and   threads : 256,1,1

```
__global__ void matrix_vector_multi_gpu_1_256(float *A_d, float *B_d, float *C_d, float *Log_d){
    int i;

    A_d[threadIdx.x]=0.0F;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        A_d[threadIdx.x]=A_d[threadIdx.x]+B_d[threadIdx.x*N+i]*C_d[i];
    }
    //lock Start about Log_d
    //__threadfence();
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if(Log_d[j]==0){
            Log_d[j]=threadIdx.x + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Stop the lock


}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some more information on what the `matrix_vector_multi_gpu_1_256` kernel function is supposed to do. In this way, you will probably receive a more focused help. The function at hands seems to be supposed to perform some sort of matrix-vector multiplication but, at a first glance, something seems to be missing, in particular what `Log_d` should contain.

Comment: By `__threadfence()`, the device waits until all global and shared accesses made by the calling thread are visible to 1) All threads in the threadblock for shared memory accesses; 2) all threads in the device for global memory accesses. In your case, it seems that you need simultaneous accesses (reads and writes) to the same memory locations (i.e., `Log_d[j]`) and perhaps this is a case when atomic operations could be better fit. I'm not sure if `__threadfence()` alone will guarantee coherency of the memory loads required by the `if` predicate.

Comment: Have you set the compilation environment for Fermi or Kepler (sm_2x or sm_3x)? `__threadfence()` is not supported in the default sm_10 architecture which nvcc will try and use.

Comment: there is a specific cuda sdk sample usinng threadfence.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you could provide some more information on what the `matrix_vector_multi_gpu_1_256` kernel function is supposed to do.

By `__threadfence()`, the device waits until all global and shared accesses made by the calling thread are visible to:

1. All threads in the threadblock for shared memory accesses;
2. All threads in the device for global memory accesses.

An example of using `__threadfence()` is available in the `threadFenceReduction` of the CUDA SDK.

In the example, the reduction is performed on an arbitrary sized array in a single kernel invocation. The thread blocks perform partial reductions and the kernel keeps track of how many blocks have finished by an atomic increment of a global counter.  If the ticket value is equal to the number of thread blocks, then the block holding the ticket knows that it is the last block to finish.  This last block is responsible for summing the results of all the other blocks.

In order to make this approach properly working, it must be ensured that before a block takes a ticket, all of its memory transactions have completed. This is accomplished by `__threadfence()`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. but, I couldn't use the __threadfence, what is the name of include file?

Comment: There is no include file necessary to use `__threadfence()`  If you're saying you couldn't use it because of the red underline, that is a separate issue that you've now discovered.

Comment: Thank you everyone, and I tryed something. but I couldn't use threadfence. and please show me sample code with the __threadfence().or tell me sample code's url .